# What's wrong with the VS.net ASP.net designer

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, tabcontainer

I've seen this happen in both VS.net 2012 and VS.net 2015.
Whenever I use a tabcontainer within a web form and put several tabs in it ***without*** a width setting, within the VS ide, the designer the screen looks like this:
[image]

But if I put a width in the tabcontainer, say 500px, it looks fine.
Now when I run it ***without*** the width, the web page looks fine.

I know I should probably just ignore the designer screen but it comes in very handy at design time.  Hence why I'm sure they called it "Designer"

Is there a setting I'm missing in VS that will allow the designer to work correctly?  Or some code I can put into it?

John

Comment: I never use the designer - work with the HTML in your ASPX code view.

Comment: If there was a way to fix this using a setting, do you think there would be a setting? I'd just keep it on... :P Looking at the amount of updates to the (ASP.NET) designer seems to show that almost noöne actually uses the designer for anything complex. You can field a bug report, but I wouldn't hold my breath :)

Comment: I have no problem working working with the HTML in my ASPX code view.  The issue I run into there is I'm rather new to this & quite honestly I don't know where to put a lot of the code I start with.  Hence the use of the designer.  It's not only helpful but insightful to know I can drag and drop an object and it puts the code in where it needs to be.
Once that is done I have no issue working with the code only.